# Under Windows, is it valid to have 2 Windows open with same dialog ID

Tags: c++, mfc

Using the MFC, I have multiple derived classes

```
class CImageView : public CFormView
{
};
```

and open 3 windows all with the same dialog ID. 
Is that valid and they wont interfere with each other?
I know it is not valid to have the same dialog ID for child windows within the dialog.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. It's just the resource id identifying the dialog resource to use to create the window. The resulting view windows are actually created with different/unique window handle (HWND) values. The reason child controls should not have duplicate ID's is because it would confuse API's like GetDlgItem, which are used to retrieve a specific control's HWND based on the ID specified.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1):

Only child windows have control ID's. Pop-up windows do not have a control ID; the API has no way of setting one. If you look at the documentation for [CreateWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw), you'll see that the `hMenu` argument is overloaded. It's used to set a control ID only when creating a child window.

The dialog ID you are referring to really is the identifier used to look up a [DIALOGEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/dialogex-resource) resource in the executable image's resource section. Once the dialog is created, that ID is gone. Using multiple dialogs created from the same dialog template is safe, and multiple instances will not interfere with each other.